# why ajax return the error response message in a laravel project ? what the possible reasons?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Before anything , I have searched for a solution for my issue here in SOF and in the internet but I didn't found the useful solution for my code :/

I write a code for getting products prices in an e-commerce laravel project depends on a product size ,
just for testing I want to (alert) the size id , and that is my js code where I use ajax :

***edited***

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#selSize").change(function(){
     var idSize = $(this).val();
     var arr = idSize.split('/');
     var productID = arr[0];
     var sizeID = arr[1];
     //alert(productID);
     $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        data: {sizeID:sizeID},
        dataType: 'application/json' ,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url:productID+'/get-products-price',
        success:function(resp){
            alert(resp);
        },error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
          }
     });
   });
});
```

and that is my html code where I browsing the product possible sizes :

```
<h3 class="my-3">Product Sizes</h3>
   @if(count($sizes) > 0)
   <select id="selSize" name="size"style="width:180px;margin-bottom:40px;height:30px;">
         <option>Select size</option>
         @foreach($sizes as $size)
             <option value="{{$product->id}}/{{$size->id}}">({{$size->width}},
                                            {{$size->height}},
                                            {{$size->length}}, 
                                            {{$size->thickness}})
                                           (cm)
             </option>
         @endforeach
    </select>
    @endif
```

and that is my controller function that I used :

```
public function getProductPrice(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;
}
```

and that where I do the routing :

```
Route::get('{id}/get-products-price' , 'SizesController@getProductPrice');
```

finally the alert it shown to me says : (localhost says  undefined) , mean return the error alert from ajax , why ?

the url shown in network console is (http://localhost/AishaStore/public/details/11/get-products-price?sizeID=2)

I hope I found the solution by your help

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?

Comment: You have to debug your code

Comment: just alert the error response msg from ajax I don't know what is it 

how to debug it and why

Comment: it give that to me at console (GET localhost/AishaStore/public/details/%7B%7B%20url('/… 404 (Not Found))

Comment: your  type:'get', but you are posting id ????

Comment: I am not posting I just call it , where the posting ?

Comment: it give me that when print error message ( (jquery.min.js:4 GET localhost/AishaStore/public/details/… 500 (Internal Server Error)))

Comment: and localhost says (undefined)

Comment: Do you check what you getting in network tab on you console of your browser.. on try to do button  submit..

Comment: it give that pro (exception: "ErrorException"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\AishaStore\storage\framework\views\fd07c7172a335e210069af632d15562e6bd5d2cd.php"
line: 19
message: "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\AishaStore\resources\views\details\show.blade.php)"
)
but where is the name I passed ??

Comment: check that file in storage->framwork->views ``fd07c7172a335e210069af632d15562e6bd5d2cd`` its not the name passed , its in your blade..

Comment: I found it in  storage->framwork->views , what I do for it now ?

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost/AishaStore/public/details/get-products-price?idSize=2
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
what the wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

In your ajax parameters add :

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Let me know if it worked but i think this is the part you are missing cause you don't define the dataType of your variables you are sending to the backend. Happened to me also sometimes that i forgot it.

Also you can add:

```
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

***Edit:***

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}
```

Print your error message so you know what's the error of the ajax in order to debug.

***New Edit:***

Based on the feedback from the comments you are missing the id in your url:

```
Route::get('{id}/get-products-price' , 'SizesController@getProductPrice')->name('get-products-price');
```

Comment: Does your code reach the backend? There must be an error somewhere. Instead of console.log "Error" show the actual error. Edited my answer to help you do that.

Comment: it give that to me at console (GET http://localhost/AishaStore/public/details/%7B%7B%20url('/get-products-price')%20%7D%7D?idSize=2 404 (Not Found))

Comment: Then your url is wrong. The problem comes from your path. Check your url again and put the right path there.

Comment: I don't see anything error in the path , can you check it please :/

Comment: The url you posted is not right. Check it's format. There is the word: `url('/get-products-price')` inside the url which does not make sense

Comment: Added another solution maybe this one works check it out. Of course keep the rest as is from my first answer. You are passing a json so you need json headers.

Comment: when I display the error message as you said it give me that error message (jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/AishaStore/public/details/%7B%7Broute('get-products-price')%7D%7D?idSize=2 500 (Internal Server Error))

Comment: That's really weird that your url is treated as a string and is concatenated in the url like a variable

Comment: I saw that :/ , so what to do that really weird

Comment: just another shot. Add the json headers etc etc and in your first approach remove the slash (/) like : `url: 'get-products-price',`

Comment: still the same :/

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost/AishaStore/public/details/get-products-price?idSize=2
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
what the wrong ?

Comment: What should be the right route? How do you access the get-products-price in order to get it's values?

Comment: py select new size from a selection drop menu

Comment: No i mean how do you access the get-product-price route. Not inside the ajax through your browser or postman. Saw me the full path that works.

Comment: http://localhost/AishaStore/public/details/11 this is a product details page after that I select a new size there get an error because when go to get-products-price the url seem like http://localhost/AishaStore/public/details/get-products-price?idSize=2 , that without product id so it give an error that it don't know the product data , so what tho solution :/

Comment: so the correct url would be `localhost/AishaStore/public/details/11/get-products-price?idSize=2`  ?

Comment: yes , but if I write it manually in the browser it gives (page not found)

Comment: now I realize that :/ , where I should correct the url ?

Comment: Edited my answer have a look and try to use the above url to access it with 11 hardcoded first.

Comment: Not yet let's see if it works. Please try to access it like a normal url don't interfere with ajax at the moment. Use postman or your browser since it's a get to test it.

Comment: sorry for being late but the electricity turn off in our town ,, it didn't work :/

Comment: the js function is show an alert if I remove the ajax from it but sure not reach to the getProductPrice function

Comment: this url on browser (http://localhost/AishaStore/public/details/11/get-products-price?idSize=2) with this route (Route::get('{id}/get-products-price' , 'ProductsController@getProductPrice');
) give me (page not found) and the error in network console is (Request URL: ws://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/DE029DC3-7F38-E844-929B-F761333D39E1/websocket?url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FAishaStore%2Fpublic%2Fdetails%2F11%2Fget-products-price%3FidSize%3D2&nocache=1546014306846 with status code 101)

Comment: I think that the problem will solved if I pass the product id into ajax url , but how can I get that product Id

Comment: I update my route to (Route::get('details/{id}/get-products-price' , 'ProductsController@getProductPrice');) and it give code 200 ok , but alert still show (Error) , but if I write all url path in browser it print the price in a white page , but why still show error so it enter the error function in ajax

Comment: Do you pass the id in your ajax url? What is the error showing now? There is a chance that the ajax works and sends the data but still goes to "error" function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here:

```
url:'/get-products-price',
```

change it to:

```
url: "{{ url('/get-products-price') }}",  // url() function will generate the right url for the application
```

and try again and open the console to check the exact response.

Comment: it didn't work , and I don't think that is the reason bcz it return error

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking for the CSRF token as a POST parameter, the VerifyCsrfToken middleware will also check for the X-CSRF-TOKEN request header. You could, for example, store the token in a HTML meta tag:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then, once you have created the `meta` tag, you can instruct a library like jQuery to automatically add the token to all request headers. This provides simple, convenient CSRF protection for your AJAX based applications:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
})
```

;

Try add this in your controller

```
 return response()->json(['success'=>'Record is successfully added']);
```

Comment: still give me that (GET http://localhost/AishaStore/public/details/%7B%7B%20url('get-products-price')%20%7D%7D?idSize=2 500 (Internal Server Error))

Comment: Unless you have disabled VerifyCsrfToken middleware, you'll want to add the X-CSRF-TOKEN header to your request

Comment: how to add it and where ?

Comment: I send you link if you would like I update my answer

Comment: still the same:/ 
it give that at network console (exception: "ErrorException"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\AishaStore\storage\framework\views\fd07c7172a335e210069af632d15562e6bd5d2cd.php"
line: 20
message: "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\AishaStore\resources\views\details\show.blade.php)"
)

Comment: it is another error  If you dump it out you can see the problem

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost/AishaStore/public/details/get-products-price?idSize=2
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
what the wrong ?